CrewAI PDFSearchTool throws error when using AZURE OPENAI API
Why am I getting the following error when trying to use PDFSearchTool for PDF RAG Search using CrewAI?
I am using Azure OpenAPI AI, with gpt-4o and text-embedding-ada-002 model for passing into CrewAI code. I have taken reference from https://docs.crewai.com/tools/pdfsearchtool#pdfsearchtool where it says to use custom config if we are using other model such as azure_openai.
from multiprocessing import process
from crewai import Agent, Crew, Process, Task,LLM
from crewai_tools import PDFSearchTool
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import litellm
litellm.set_verbose = True

import os

load_dotenv()


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "random key"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2022-01-01"

llm = LLM(
    model="azure/gpt-4o",
    base_url="https://<azurereopen ai resource name>.openai.azure.com",
    api_key="key copied from endpoint section on azure openai"
)

config = dict(
    llm=dict(
        provider="azure_openai",
        config=dict(
            model="gpt-4o",
            api_key="key copied from endpoint section on azure openai",
            deployment_name="https://<azurereopen ai resource name>.openai.azure.com"
        ),
    ),
    embedder=dict(
        provider="azure_openai",
        config=dict(
            model="text-embedding-ada-002",
            deployment_name="https://<azurereopen ai resource name>.openai.azure.com",
            api_key="key copied from endpoint section on azure openai"
        ),
    )
)

# --- Tools ---
pdf_search_tool = PDFSearchTool(
   config=config,
    pdf='./example_home_inspection.pdf'
)

# --- Agents ---
research_agent = Agent(
    role="Research Agent",
    goal="Search through the PDF to find relevant answers",
    allow_delegation=False,
    verbose=True,
    backstory=(
        """
        The research agent is adept at searching and 
        extracting data from documents, ensuring accurate and prompt responses.
        """
    ),
    tools=[pdf_search_tool],
    llm=llm

)

professional_writer_agent = Agent(
    role="Professional Writer",
    goal="Write professional emails based on the research agent's findings",
    allow_delegation=False,
    verbose=True,
    backstory=(
        """
        The professional writer agent has excellent writing skills and is able to craft 
        clear and concise emails based on the provided information.
        """
    ),
    tools=[]
)


# --- Tasks ---
answer_customer_question_task = Task(
    description=(
        """
        Answer the customer's questions based on the home inspection PDF.
        The research agent will search through the PDF to find the relevant answers.
        Your final answer MUST be clear and accurate, based on the content of the home
        inspection PDF.

        Here is the customer's question:
        {customer_question}
        """
    ),
    expected_output="""
        Provide clear and accurate answers to the customer's questions based on 
        the content of the home inspection PDF.
        """,
    tools=[pdf_search_tool],
    agent=research_agent,
    llm=llm
)

write_email_task = Task(
    description=(
        """
        - Write a professional email to a contractor based 
            on the research agent's findings.
        - The email should clearly state the issues found in the specified section 
            of the report and request a quote or action plan for fixing these issues.
        - Ensure the email is signed with the following details:
        
            Best regards,

            AuthorName
        """
    ),
    expected_output="""
        Write a clear and concise email that can be sent to a contractor to address the 
        issues found in the home inspection report.
        """,
    tools=[],
    agent=professional_writer_agent,
)

# --- Crew ---
crew = Crew(
    agents=[research_agent],
    tasks=[answer_customer_question_task],
    process=Process.sequential
)
customer_question = input(
    "Which section of the report would you like to generate a work order for?\n"
)

result = crew.kickoff(inputs={"customer_question": customer_question})
print(result)

I am using poetry for package and dependency management and here are package details:
python = ">=3.10.0,<3.12"
python-dotenv = "1.0.0"
crewai-tools = ">=0.4.26"
crewai = ">=0.41.1"
langchain-anthropic = ">=0.1.20"
langchain-openai=">=0.1.7"

When I try to run python <path to py file>.py it throws:
    Agent: Research Agent
Task: Answer the customer's questions based on the home inspection PDF.
The research agent will search through the PDF to find the relevant answers. Your final answer MUST be clear and accurate, based on the content of the home inspection PDF.

Here is the customer's question:Exterior

LiteLLM.Info: If you need to debug this error, use litellm.set_verbose=True'.



    raise AuthenticationError(
litellm.exceptions.AuthenticationError: litellm.AuthenticationError: AuthenticationError: OpenAIException - The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable

